# NestJS Bull queues - Missing lock for job failed

Tags: typescript, redis, queue, nestjs, bull

I'm using Bull with NestJS to handle a jobs queue. In the process handler I would like to mark a job as failed instead of completed, but it seems - also reading the documentation - that the `Job#moveToFailed()` method is allowed only on waiting jobs.

In fact, it triggers an error saying "Missing lock for job ${jobId} failed".
But, calling the `Job#moveToFailed` with the `ignoreLock` parameter to true everything goes fine.

What happens if I ignore the lock moving a job to failed? Is there some side effect? In my scenario, the queue jobs will be always consumed by the same `@Processor`.

Here it is the piece of code I'm running for test purpose:

```
@Process()
async transcode(job: Job<unknown>): Promise<any> {
  const jobData = job.data as Record<string, string | unknown>
  if (jobData == null) {
    await job.moveToFailed({ message: 'Hook marked as failed because of missing data' })
    return
  }

  // do other stuff for job execution..
}
```

Comment: set `ignoreLock` [DOC](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#jobmovetofailed)

Comment: as I wrote @EmptyBrain, is there some side effect telling bull to ignore the lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass false as a token parameter (that ignores the token check).

```
await job.moveToFailed({ message: 'Hook marked as failed because of missing data' }, false)
```

I was able to add '0' instead of false and that worked for me, but the parameter type is Boolean like mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to edit. We arrived at the same conclusion, it seems the only way to make it work properly.

Comment: Its throwing error like `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.`

Comment: Use false in place of "0". 
The type looks like this:

(method) Bull.Job<number>.moveToFailed(errorInfo: {
    message: string;
}, ignoreLock?: boolean): Promise<[any, Bull.JobId]>

Comment: @RiteshKhatri you can pass `undefined` for the token param